# How to build linux shared libraries in windows hard disk using linux based platform?

Tags: linux, windows, opencv, shared-libraries, mount

I am building open cv libraries in windows from linux based computer remotely using cmake and i get this error after running following commands :

mount.cifs  //10.164.5.10/tgupta /mnt/open_cv -o username=tgupta,password=passwd
and then following this tutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

I am stuck at this error after running make command

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../../bin/libopencv_core.so   
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not supported  
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not supported  
make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0] Error 1  
make[1]: *** [opencv/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same thing, i.e.

- Building OpenCV on a shared external drive from a linux guest in a virtual machine running on a windows host,
- and I got the same error regarding the symlink.

The following worked for me:

> 1. Shut down the Virtual Machine and also VirtualBox completely,
> 2. Open cmd.exe and type the following,
>
> ```
> $ cd C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
> $ VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME
> $ VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
> ```
>
> where in my case, **VM_NAME**=*ubuntu14* and **SHARE_NAME**=*D_DRIVE* (Yes, remove the "*sf_*" prefix).
>
> 3. Open VirtualBox as Administrator, and start Ubuntu/(your linux guest), rebuild OpenCV, everything works fine now!

And I got to it from here: ["Virtualbox Sharedfolder Symbolic Link Error"](https://simbaforrest.github.io/blog/2016/03/19/virtualbox-sharedfolder-symbolic-link-error.html).

**Note:** Come to think of it, one small variation, though in my case, I guess makes a big difference - my external device is *NTFS* formatted. So as far as I know, *NTFS* does support some sort of symlinks. I am not sure if this solution also works for *FAT (VFAT/FAT32)*-format drives.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem,
I found a solution:

The idea is to make the libraries pointing to a directory in the linux file system, let say `/home/<user>/libopencv`.
I edited the file `CMakeLists.txt` and changed:

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH         "${OpenCV_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

into

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH         "/home/<user>/libopencv")
```

then run your CMake command and `make` should perform well !
The libs are light, and you still have the heavy part in the external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work because you are keeping the files on a filesystem which doesn't support creating symlinks.

You should build everything on a filesystem from Linux like ext4, btrfs, or something else that's compliant, archive the files resulted from you build and then copy them to the Windows share.

Alternatively, you could share your Linux filesystem with Windows with Samba instead of sharing the windows directory with Linux.

Comment: As I don't have enough memory in my linux platform so sharing linux filesystem with windows is not feasible .Please tell me how to build .so(that is shared file) file of open cv in windows only that is cross - compile thing .

Comment: You have to build the library on a linux compatible filesystem. Then, if you can't share that filesystem, just copy the lib over to the Windows share.

Comment: Actually I need to built open cv libraries in windows only which can run on linux .So basically I need opposite of what you told that is building linux based libraries in windows then copying it to linux .

Comment: I don't think you explained clearly what you want to do. I explained why it doesn't compile and I think that if you want to actually make it compile you should read the solution I proposed again.

Comment: You can't compile Linux libs on windows. More than that, normally you shouldn't even compile linux libs on a different linux distro than the one you intend them for.